# A simple JavaFX 2.x animation task

Tags: javafx-2

I have done animations in FlashProfessional (CS 6), which sucks by the way (crashes constantly without saving last modifications, produces enormous files, works inconsistently and so on). I have hard time to figure out how the following simple task can be done in JavaFX 2.x (probably because my background is in Flash): a rectangle that exists in a constant location from t=0 to t=100, and after that it is deleted from the Scene.

In Flash, I could create a keyframe at t=0 in which I draw a rectangle. Then I create second keyframe at t=100  in which the rectangle is deleted. That simple.

In JavaFX, why I can’t just write `timeline.getKeyFrames().addAll(new KeyFrame(new Duration(100), new Rectangle(10, 10, 25, 25)));` or like.

Please help me and provide the code. I’m lost in these KeyValues and Java properties, why I need those anyway…

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that task you can just remove rectangle after 100 ms. JavaFX unlike Flash is not built about keyframes -- they are optional functionality and used only if you need real animation, e.g. scaling of an object. See next tutorial for more info: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/animations/jfxpub-animations.htm

And demonstrating code:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    final Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(10, 70, 50, 50);
    final Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(10, 150, 50, 50);

    Button btn = new Button("Play");
    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
            // this "timeline" just call a handler after 500 ms which hides rectangle
            TimelineBuilder.create().keyFrames(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(500), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
                    rect1.setVisible(false);
                }
            })).build().play();

            // this timeline hides rectangle 2 with animation
            // changing scaleXProperty() from 1 (default) to 0
            TimelineBuilder.create().keyFrames(
                    new KeyFrame(
                        Duration.millis(500), 
                        new KeyValue(rect2.scaleXProperty(), 0))
                    ).build().play();
        }
    });

    Pane root = new Pane();
    root.getChildren().addAll(rect1, rect2, btn);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 300);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```